# Creating an automatic code feedback for class

Tags: java

I'm trying to create a server application that accepts uploaded Mathematica files (that follow a certain API), then run a few tests on modules defined within those files. This is for a course where automated feedback would be very beneficial. As of right now, I've looked into J/Link, but I'm trying to figure out to to process .nb files.

Does anyone know how to execute all cells of a .nb within the server (whether in Java or shell), then run the functions defined within that file?

Thanks

Comment: Just as side note: You don't want to execute arbitrary code without some measure of sand boxing e.g. running your server as a virtual machine.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!